# how to compile tidesdk package to get .exe file out of it?

Tags: cross-platform, desktop-application, tidesdk

Im trying to compile hello world package made from tide but couldnot make anything out of it. I tried compiling using tidebuilder.py but for some reason it seems not to be working. I installed tide sdk and tried to import but this package womt get imported.
 How do I compile this file to get .exe application for Windows?

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere on this? I tried zipping up my files.

Answer (score 0):

Steps 5 and 6 in this guide explain how to create an .exe file:

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started